# How to fix date /Date(xxxxxxxxxxxxx)/ in asp.net mvc?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, visual-studio, datetime

Im a beginner at programming and i want to show my datatable from my database server to web, i saw a tutorial video on youtube on how to show datatable in asp.net mvc. Supposedly, my Table shows the attendance Date and Time of a person but when i run the program the column for date and time shows like this /Date(xxxxxxxxxxxxx)/ but in the database it looks fine. What should i do to fix it.

Below is my view page:

```html
 $(document).ready(function () {

           

            $("#AttendanceTable").DataTable(
                {
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": "/Attendance/GetList",
                        "type": "GET",
                      

                    },
                    "columns": [
                        { "data": "PersonInformationId" },
                        { "data": "AttendanceTime" },
                        { "data": "ActionType" },

                    ]
```

This is what my Controller looks like

```html
        public ActionResult GetList()
        {
            using (DBModel db = new DBModel())
            {
                var AttList = db.Attendances.ToList<Attendance>();
            
                return Json(new { data = AttList }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
               
            }
```

I've read some articles that you need to convert Json Date to normal date format in JavaScript but i dont know how.

Comment: That was the default format for dates using the default JSON serializer in old versions of ASP.Net, later ones use JSON.Net or System.Text.Json (in ASP.Net Core 3.0 onwards) which use ISO-8601 formats, e.g. 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:dd:ss'. What version of ASP.Net are you using?

Comment: ASP.Net 4.0 , ASP.Net Core 3.1

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it! This code worked for me with date&time format [MM/dd/YYYY HH:mm am:pm]

```html
function (jsonDate) {
                                var d = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
                                var m, day;
                                m = d.getMonth() + 1;
                                if (m < 10)
                                    m = '0' + m
                                if (d.getDate() < 10)
                                    day = '0' + d.getDate()
                                else
                                    day = d.getDate();
                                var formattedDate = m + "/" + day + "/" + d.getFullYear();
                                var hours = (d.getHours() < 10) ? "0" + d.getHours() : d.getHours();
                                var dayMode = hours < 12 ? "am" : "pm"; 
                                var hours12 = hours <= 12 ? (hours == 0 ? 12 : hours) : hours- 12;
                                var minutes = (d.getMinutes() < 10) ? "0" + d.getMinutes() : d.getMinutes();
                                var formattedTime = hours12 + ":" + minutes + dayMode;
                                formattedDate = formattedDate + " " + formattedTime;
                                return formattedDate;
```